# Does the devtools package include git?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, git

In the Arch Linux standard packages, does devtools include git or do I need to install git separately?

How can I figure out the answer to similar questions on my own?

Comment: `pacman -Si devtools`.

Answer (score 3):

[The `devtools` package description](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/devtools/) shows that `devtools` depends on `git`; so while it doesn’t *include* `git`, installing it will result in `git` being installed too.

To answer this kind of question yourself, look the package up in [the Arch Linux package database](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/). This will show you the package’s availability, its dependencies, and the files it contains.

Comment: >"How can I figure out the answer to similar questions on my own?"<--

Search for the package in [the Arch Linux package database](https://www.archlinux.org/) and read the dependencies.

Comment: pacman can tell you this, you don't need a website: `pacman -Si devtools`